# What is wrong with this list in R?

Tags: r

I'm sure this is a very silly issue. The following is a subset of a larger list that is causing some problems when evaluating:

```
list(Time=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 ), Site=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31,  32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,  47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13,  14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,  29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,  44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,  37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,  34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,  49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,  46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,  25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,  40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,  37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,  34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,  49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,  46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50))
```

There must be an error because R thinks that the expression is not complete:

[image]

The curious thing is that `Time` and `Site` evaluate correctly. But I can't figure out what is needed. Does anyone know what is wrong with this list? And is there an online checker for R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you're trying to read it in as one line.  I know in RGui this results in the line stopping if it's too long.  I broke it up better like this and all is fine:

```
list(
    Time=c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1, 
        1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
        2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,  2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
        3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,  
        3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
        4,  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
        5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,  5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
        6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
        6, 6, 6, 6,  6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 
        7, 7, 7, 7, 7,  7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 
        8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,  8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
        9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
        9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,  10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 
        11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,  11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 
        12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 
        12,  12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 
    ), 
    Site=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,  17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
        30, 31,  32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,  47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
        10, 11, 12, 13,  14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28,  29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
        38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43,  44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
        18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25,  26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,  41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 
        46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,  7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,  22, 23, 24, 25, 
        26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,  37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1,  2, 3, 4, 
        5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,  19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,  
        34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48,  49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
        14, 15,  16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 
        42, 43, 44, 45,  46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 
        22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 
        50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,  25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 
        30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39,  40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,  6, 7, 8, 9, 
        10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21,  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,  37, 
        38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1,  2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,  
        19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,  34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
        47, 48,  49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15,  16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 
        27, 28, 29, 30,  31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45,  46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 
        6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,  13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27,  28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 
        35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42,  43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50
     )
)
```

Comment: Wow. I didn't know about it. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, this also happens in the regular R interpreter.

Comment: @RobertSmith: "regular" is not well-defined; it is console-dependent.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Do you mean that the R interpreter (the one that comes with the installation) depends on distribution?

Comment: @RobertSmith: No, the console does (and console != interpreter). The Windows binary ships with GUI and terminal consoles, and there's a Mac GUI console, etc.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Frequently, people call "interpreter" what you're describing as "console". Using your definition, I meant the terminal-based console that ships with R installations.